# Deriving EC keypairs pairs via PKCS11?

Tags: smartcard, hsm, pkcs11

I'm a bit confused with PKCS11 (v3) standard...
In particular, it's blurry to me if one can invoke `C_DeriveKey`, passing, say, `CKM_SHA512_KEY_DERIVATION` (or some HKDF) to it as the mechanism and also set the following in the template:

- `CKA_CLASS = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY`
- `CKA_KEY_TYPE = CKK_EC` or `CKA_KEY_TYPE = CKK_EC_EDWARDS`

such that two objects, `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` and `CKO_PUBLIC_KEY`, are created with (respectively) `CKA_SIGN` and `CKA_VERIFY` being set to `true`.  So the general intention is to be able to generate a `CKO_GENERIC_SECRET` and then use that secret with some KDF (e.g., HKDF) to produce multiple ECDSA/EdDSA keypairs, maybe also symmetric keys for AES.

And the reason I'm not sure is that PKCS11 (as well as different interpretations of it) does say things like '*[...] the capability of deriving a secret key [...]*' and also '*[...] these mechanisms allow derivation of keys [...]*,' but the meaning of 'key' and 'secret key' is ambiguous to me.
Does it mean that `CKA_CLASS` is limited to symmetric keys only, and so must be `CKO_SECRET_KEY`? Or does it mean that both `CKO_SECRET_KEY` and `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` can be used?
Intuitively, it should be rather easy and natural to support `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` as well — after all, the generation of EC keypair always starts from gathering some entropy that is then interpreted as a big integer modulo something or whatever...

So it would be super helpful if one could advise:

1. Is it legit, as per PKCS11, to use `C_DeriveKey` with `CKM_SHA512_KEY_DERIVATION`/`CKM_HKDF_DERIVE`/etc to obtain `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY`s?
2. If not possible, are there any vendors that do allow it (i.e., the derivation of `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY` from `CKO_SECRET_KEY`) via vendor-defined mechanisms?
3. If it is possible, what are vendors that do support it?

---

I was trying to figure it out by looking at docs of different vendors (Thales, Nitrokey, nCipher, AWS Cloud HSM, etc.), but that wasn't helpful — mainly, they tell which key types are supported for the `hBaseKey`, rather than what key types can be generated. Neither was I able to get my hands on a good all-encompassing HSM emulator to play with it...
And while I'm aware of SoftHSM2 and Utimaco simulator, that doesn't help — the SoftHSM2 [doesn't support](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/blob/2.6.1/src/lib/SoftHSM.cpp#L7068-L7076) the derivation of asymmetric keys. And Utimaco requires registration, approval of which doesn't come for a week now...

Comment: check your spam folder.  Utimaco's supply chain send an email to you, to let you know a) your reg failed because you didn't give legit information, or b) that your account was activated.  If you can't find the reg email, you can also just try to log in with the credentials you provided.  If you didn't give a legit email, can't help :) (disclosure: I work for Utimaco)

Comment: Looking at the underlying question, I can see a way to do it, but it involves deriving a secret value of the correct length, exporting it as plain text and then re-importing it as C_CreateObject with a suitable template that causes it to be seen as an eg Edwards key.  Which, admittedly breaks the fundamental "Idea" of the HSM:  Protect the keys.

Comment: @rip... As for "_check your spam folder [...]_". I did – found nothing... Also, I can't log in: it says "_Error:Authentication failed. Please try again._". If I try resetting the password, there's no email either. And the email is correct – the one I'm using on the website regex-matches the one I copied from Gmail UI. And if I try to register with that again, it says that the user already exists.

Comment: @rip... As for exporting the key as plain text. I was not even considering this approach seriously because, as you said, it is not ... safe.
Also, are you trying to say that what I'd like to do is inherently not supported by PKCS and/or HSMs?

Comment: When I search on your last name, it looks like you provided insufficient information.  We are governed by German law, and we can only provide the simulator to verifiable entities.  The problem is the company "N/A" and we also can not accept @gmail addresses, sorry.  Needs to be a legitimate enterprise, an email linked to that enterprise, and the physical address you provide needs to be for the company you work for.

Comment: "inherently supported" is HSM dependent.  An HSM will provide specific operations, algorithms, mechanisms etc.  Whether an arbitrary HSM supports the specific thing you are looking for depends on the HSM implementation you're talking to.  Utimaco's GP HSMs support the SHA512_KEY_DERIVATION mechanism.  But according to the spec, it just says "if key type is provided, and the length is well known...".  ... would need to experiment to see if it works out of the box for private keys.  Our HSMs are programmable and you could add your own VDM if you can program in C and want to go that route.

Comment: @rip... Re Utimaco being programmable — that sounds cool! It looks like a potential solution to my case :) Thanks! Regarding the company I work for, that's a bit tricky because, as I said in the form, I'm a private entrepreneur (sole proprietorship, if you wish) – that is, I'm a director of a legal entity that consists only of me :) (_and, of course, I am able to provide additional info that will help to ensure such an entity exists_). In UA, the field '_company_' is usually not filled or filled with 'FOP <PERSON_FULL_NAME>' in such cases — will the letter option do for Utimaco?

Comment: If I look for your name on LinkedIn, will I be able to find you there?

Also: About the programmability:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258578/examples-of-custom-key-restriction-policies-for-hsms/258620#258620

Comment: @rip... sure, here's my LinkedIn page: https://www.linkedin.com/in/nk185 . And thanks for the link you shared :)